# REST API with Single Page Application over HTTPS on Firefox only

Tags: rest, firefox, https

I am developing a web service using REST API. This REST API is running on port 6443 for HTTPS. Client is going to be a Single page application running on port 443 for HTTPS on same machine. The problem I am facing is:

While I hit the url say: https://mymachine.com/new_ui I get certificate exception for an invalid certificate because I use a self signed one, so mymachine.com:443 gets added to server exception. But still requests doen't go to REST API as they are running on https://mymachine.com:6443/restservice. If I manually add mymachine.com:6443 to server exception on firefox it works but it will not be the case in production for customers.

Some options that I thought are: 
1. Give another pop up and ask to add REST server on port 6443 exception too.But this doesn't look proper as why an end user should accept the cerf for same domain twice.  Also REST api server port can change.

2. Can we programmatically add exception for domain and both the ports in one shot? Ofcourse with the consent of the user. 3. Use a reverse proxy. But then its going to have memory footprint on our system. Also it will be time consuming.

Please suggest some options. How do I deal with it. Thank you

Comment: I think this will give you an ide of what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS